# Add divider between right side navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue that I'm trying to solve with the right side of my nav bar.

1) I'd like to have the nav look like this "Login | Contact" - Currently there's no divider in between, but when I add the divider line, it doesn't line up after the Login text.

If I add it as another "li" it doesn't render properly. Any other way to display it?

Check out the bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/huskydawgs/waaBbWFaI1

Here' my html:

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container topnav">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://red.org/wp-content/plugins/a8c-stripe/img/red_logo.png" alt="Onvia Exchange">
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
              <li>|</li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `<a>` tags around the divider.

`<li><a>|</a></li>`

My guess is that bootstrap has a style that is using the `<a>` tag that the `<li>` tag does not use. By adding the `<a>` tag it is adding the same style as the other two elements around the line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a pseudo instead of an actual element? The pipe character isn't meant to be a "divider".

```
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(50% - .5em);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not using css border like this:

```css
.navbar-right > li{
  border-right:1px solid #000; /* put any color you want*/
}

.navbar-right > li:last-child{
  border-right:none;  
}
```

I think it's more simple than using HTML.